# "'New-AzureStorageContext' is not recognized," Yet the Module is Installed

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have installed both the Az PowerShell module and .NET Framework 4.7.2 per the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.0.0 yet the client still can't find the module!

```
PS C:\Scripts> get-module Az

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0.1      Az


PS C:\Scripts> get-module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0.1      Az
Script     1.0.0      Az.Accounts                         {Add-AzEnvironment, Clear-AzContext, Clear-AzDefault, Conn...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Aks                              {Get-AzAks, Import-AzAksCredential, New-AzAks, Remove-AzAk...
Script     1.0.0      Az.AnalysisServices                 {Add-AzAnalysisServicesAccount, Export-AzAnalysisServicesI...
Script     1.0.0      Az.ApiManagement                    {Add-AzApiManagementApiToProduct, Add-AzApiManagementProdu...
Script     1.0.0      Az.ApplicationInsights              {Get-AzApplicationInsights, Get-AzApplicationInsightsApiKe...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Automation                       {Export-AzAutomationDscConfiguration, Export-AzAutomationD...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Batch                            {Disable-AzBatchAutoScale, Disable-AzBatchComputeNodeSched...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Billing                          {Get-AzBillingInvoice, Get-AzBillingPeriod, Get-AzConsumpt...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Cdn                              {Confirm-AzCdnEndpointProbeURL, Disable-AzCdnCustomDomain,...
Script     1.0.0      Az.CognitiveServices                {Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccount, Get-AzCognitiveServicesAc...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Compute                          {Add-AzContainerServiceAgentPoolProfile, Add-AzImageDataDi...
Script     1.0.0      Az.ContainerInstance                {Get-AzContainerGroup, Get-AzContainerInstanceLog, New-AzC...
Script     1.0.0      Az.ContainerRegistry                {Get-AzContainerRegistry, Get-AzContainerRegistryCredentia...
Script     1.0.0      Az.DataFactory                      {Get-AzDataFactory, Get-AzDataFactoryActivityWindow, Get-A...
Script     1.0.0      Az.DataLakeAnalytics                {Add-AzDataLakeAnalyticsDataSource, Add-AzDataLakeAnalytic...
Script     1.0.0      Az.DataLakeStore                    {Add-AzDataLakeStoreFirewallRule, Add-AzDataLakeStoreItemC...
Script     1.0.0      Az.DevTestLabs                      {Get-AzDtlAllowedVMSizesPolicy, Get-AzDtlAutoShutdownPolic...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Dns                              {Add-AzDnsRecordConfig, Get-AzDnsRecordSet, Get-AzDnsZone,...
Script     1.0.0      Az.EventGrid                        {Get-AzEventGridSubscription, Get-AzEventGridTopic, Get-Az...
Script     1.0.0      Az.EventHub                         {Get-AzEventHub, Get-AzEventHubAuthorizationRule, Get-AzEv...
Script     1.0.0      Az.HDInsight                        {Add-AzHDInsightClusterIdentity, Add-AzHDInsightComponentV...
Script     1.0.0      Az.IotHub                           {Add-AzIotHubCertificate, Add-AzIotHubEventHubConsumerGrou...
Script     1.0.0      Az.KeyVault                         {Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate, Add-AzKeyVaultCertificateConta...
Script     1.0.0      Az.LogicApp                         {Get-AzIntegrationAccount, Get-AzIntegrationAccountAgreeme...
Script     1.0.0      Az.MachineLearning                  {Add-AzMlWebServiceRegionalProperty, Export-AzMlWebService...
Script     1.0.0      Az.MarketplaceOrdering              {Get-AzMarketplaceTerms, Set-AzMarketplaceTerms}
Script     1.0.0      Az.Media                            {Get-AzMediaService, Get-AzMediaServiceKeys, Get-AzMediaSe...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Monitor                          {Add-AzAutoscaleSetting, Add-AzLogProfile, Add-AzMetricAle...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Network                          {Add-AzApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, Add-Az...
Script     1.0.0      Az.NotificationHubs                 {Get-AzNotificationHub, Get-AzNotificationHubAuthorization...
Script     1.0.0      Az.OperationalInsights              {Disable-AzOperationalInsightsIISLogCollection, Disable-Az...
Script     1.0.0      Az.PolicyInsights                   {Get-AzPolicyEvent, Get-AzPolicyRemediation, Get-AzPolicyS...
Script     1.0.0      Az.PowerBIEmbedded                  {Get-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity, Get-AzPowerBIWorkspace, Ge...
Script     1.0.0      Az.RecoveryServices                 {Backup-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem, Disable-AzRecoverySe...
Script     1.0.0      Az.RedisCache                       {Export-AzRedisCache, Get-AzRedisCache, Get-AzRedisCacheFi...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Relay                            {Get-AzRelayAuthorizationRule, Get-AzRelayHybridConnection...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Resources                        {Add-AzADGroupMember, Export-AzResourceGroup, Get-AzADAppC...
Script     1.0.0      Az.ServiceBus                       {Complete-AzServiceBusMigration, Get-AzServiceBusAuthoriza...
Script     1.0.0      Az.ServiceFabric                    {Add-AzServiceFabricApplicationCertificate, Add-AzServiceF...
Script     1.0.0      Az.SignalR                          {Get-AzSignalR, Get-AzSignalRKey, New-AzSignalR, New-AzSig...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Sql                              {Add-AzSqlDatabaseToFailoverGroup, Add-AzSqlManagedInstanc...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Storage                          {Add-AzRmStorageContainerLegalHold, Add-AzStorageAccountNe...
Script     1.0.0      Az.StreamAnalytics                  {Get-AzStreamAnalyticsDefaultFunctionDefinition, Get-AzStr...
Script     1.0.0      Az.TrafficManager                   {Add-AzTrafficManagerCustomHeaderToEndpoint, Add-AzTraffic...
Script     1.0.0      Az.Websites                         {Edit-AzWebAppBackupConfiguration, Enter-AzWebAppContainer...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Con...
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString, Get-Acl...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Connect-WSMan, Disable-WSManCredSSP, Disconnect-WSMan, En...
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package, Get-Pack...
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCap...
Script     1.2        PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadlineOption, Remove-PS...


PS C:\Scripts> $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "...my storage account name..." -StorageAccountKey "...my sas key..."
New-AzureStorageContext : The term 'New-AzureStorageContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:12
+ $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "...my storage acc...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-AzureStorageContext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The error (as shown above in the output above) is:

> New-AzureStorageContext : The term 'New-AzureStorageContext' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>       script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>       correct and try again.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command [`New-AzureStorageContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontext?view=azurermps-6.13.0) you used belongs to the [`AzureRM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/overview?view=azurermps-6.13.0) powershell module, it is different from the new module [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azps-1.0.0) , you have not installed it, that caused the issue.

To fix the issue, you could refer to the solutions below.

1.Install the [`AzureRM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0) module.

2.If you want to run scripts developed for `AzureRM` using `Az`, use the `Enable/Disable-AzureRmAlias` cmdlets to add or remove aliases from AzureRM cmdlets to Az cmdlets.

Adds AzureRM cmdlet aliases for the given modules (or all modules if no modules are specified) to the current session (default), all sessions for the current user, or all session on the machine.

```
Enable-AzureRmAlias [-Module <string>] [-Scope Process | CurrentUser | LocalMachine]

Disable-AzureRmAlias [-Module <string[]>] [-Scope Process | CurrentUser | LocalMachine]
```

3.Use [`New-AzStorageContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-1.0.0) instead of `New-AzureStorageContext`, it is recommended, the `AzureRM` module is basically deprecated, essentially they call the same api and are all for ARM, you could have a try.

For more details, see : [Azure PowerShell – Cross-platform “Az” module replacing “AzureRM”](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/).

Answer (score 4):

`New-AzureStorageContext` is an old command you need if you want to continue using it with the new `AZ` module you have to `Enable-AzureRmAlias` or change command to  `New-AzStorageContext`.

**Enable-AzureRmAlias**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.0.0

**New-AzStorageContext**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontext?view=azurermps-6.13.0